# Unable To enable inline editing for Visualforce page Error: Inline Editing is supported for API Version 21 and above

Tags: visualforce, api-version

I am trying to enable inline editing for a visual force page I created. However, whenever I try to save it I get the following error, "Error: Inline Editing is supported for API Version 21 and above." How do I upgrade the API version???

Here is my code

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Contact.label}" subtitle="{!Contact.name}"/>
<apex:pageBlock mode="InlineEdit" title="{!$ObjectType.Contact.label} Detail">
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Address Information" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingStreet}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.OtherStreet}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingCity}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.OtherCity}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingState}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.OtherState}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.OtherPostalCode}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MailingCountry}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.OtherCountry}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Contact Preferences" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Best_way_to_contact__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Textable__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Access_to_Internet__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Do_Not_Call__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Access_to_Computer__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Email_Opt_Out__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Do_Not_Assign_Coach__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Do_Not_Track__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Demographics" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Gender__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Ethnicity__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Race__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Qualify_for_free_reduced_lunch__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Asian__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.English_is_first_language__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.First_Generation__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Individualized_Education_Program__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Educational_Opp_Program_Participant__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Residency__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Military_Status__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Social_Services__c}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Emergency Contact Information" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Emergency_Contact_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Emergency_Contact_Phone__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Family Information" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Relationship__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Relationship__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Education_Level__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Education_Level__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Email__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Email__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Mobile__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Mobile__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Textable__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Textable__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Other_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Other_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_1_Work_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Parent_Guardian_2_Work_Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Permanently_Reside_With__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.of_Residents_in_Household__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Dependency__c}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Spouse and Children Information" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name_of_spouse_partner__c}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name_of_child_1__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Age_of_child_1__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name_of_child_2__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Age_of_child_2__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name_of_child_3__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Age_of_child_3__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Sibling Information" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Sibling_1_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Sibling_1_High_School_Graduated_From__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Sibling_1_High_School_Graduation_Year__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Sibling_1_College_Graduated_From__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="System Information" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.CreatedById}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Record_Completeness__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.AccountId}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.LastModifiedById}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Student Record Type"/>
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:outputText value="{!Contact.RecordType.Name}"/>&nbsp;
                <apex:outputLink value="/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?id={!LEFT(Contact.id,15)}&amp;retURL=%2F{!LEFT(Contact.id,15)}">[Change]</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" title="Custom Links" columns="3">
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the *Version Settings* tab and give the page an API version of 21 or above (since you are using just a standard controller I suggest you to keep a recent API version, like 37), save and try again.